# Recaptcha testing in Laravel 5.3 not working

Tags: unit-testing, testing, laravel-5

I'm doing Authentication testing and I have this:

```
 $this->visit('/')
    ->type('Name', 'name')
    ->type('Last_name', 'last_name')
    ->type('mail@mail', 'email')
    ->type('password@password', 'password')
    ->type(VALUE-RECAPTCHA, 'g-recaptcha-response')->press('Send');
```

But, When I run the test, g-recaptcha-response is Null, and I dont know how to get this value in the test.

Thanks for your help!